# Only take specific information from text field

Tags: java, swing, date, jtextfield, simpledateformat

I was wondering how you can take just specific characters from a JTextField. For example if a JTextField has the date 20/12/2012 then how do you read only the "12" form the Field.

So is it possible and if so how or would it be easier to use multiple JTextFields?

Comment: What pattern do you want to read from JTextFields? all "12" from JTextFileds?

Comment: the numbers in the "12" place. But they will be numbers and there will always be a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach would be read full text, but split `string` based on `"/"` and take 0 index value in resulting array.

(or)

Parse String using `SimpleDateFormatter` and get Month from `Date` (assuming entered string will be always date)

If none of above works, then it would be easier to use multiple text fields

Answer (score 2):

[StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) can break up your string for you.
[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) can handle dates if you know the format in the field will be correct.
However having multiple fields for dates is common. You may just want different fields depending on your overall use of the data and user interaction with it.